# Redeclaring for-loop variables in old g++

Tags: c++, for-loop, g++, declaration, compiler-options

When running `git bisect` on some C++ code (written for GCC), I came across a compiler error generated by something along the lines of

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    long i = 0;
    printf("%ld\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This piece of code is, I beleive, perfectly standard C99 (`gcc -std=c99` compiles it fine), however, `g++` fails because of the redeclaration of `i`. The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12351531/560450 quoted the C++11 standard on this matter:

> 6.4/2 The rules for conditions apply both to selection-statements and to the for and while statements
>
> 6.4/3 If the name is re-declared in the outermost block of a substatement controlled by the condition, the declaration that
>   re-declares the name is ill-formed.
>
> 6.5.3/1 names declared in the for-init-statement are in the same declarative-region as those declared in the condition

Therefore, I am no more curious about why this is illegal C++. :-) I would just like to get it compile!

I looked at G++'s options related to language dialects. According to the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options),

> If `-ffor-scope` is specified, the scope of variables declared in a
>   *for-init-statement* is limited to the `‘for’` loop itself, as specified
>   by the C++ standard. If `-fno-for-scope` is specified, the scope of
>   variables declared in a *for-init-statement* extends to the end of the
>   enclosing scope, as was the case in old versions of G++, and other
>   (traditional) implementations of C++.

This is the only even remotely related-sounding option I could find. Oddly enough, passing `-fno-for-scope` to `g++` makes the example compile; with no warnings even with `-Wall -Wextra`. However, back to the code I would like to compile, this option generates many errors, because the variables initialized in a *for-init-statement* now have there scope extended. Clearly, this is not the solution.

*Just to clarify: I am not looking to compile C99 code with a C++ compiler, that would be foolish. I have some C++ code; `git blame` tells that the line with the redeclaration is from 2001. I would like to compile a commit which was tagged for release in 2011, therefore, I presume it was not broken at that time.*

What could I do to get it compile without modifications? Currently, I cherry-pick a commit that that renames the offending variable, but I would prefer to pass something in `CXXFLAGS` to `configure`. More generally, why does (or did) `g++` have this behaviour with `-fno-for-scope` and the redeclarations?

**EDIT:** Okay, probably I should have been more explicit. The fact that I have some code form 2001 which is broken today is just to set some context. The present-day `master` of the repository, of course, compiles without any compiler trickery. However, I am interested in how could I make `g++` behave as it behaved historically, because there is an overwhelming probability that the time the commit in question was tagged, `g++` accepted this kind of code.

**EDIT2:** After playing around with `-fdump-tree-original`, the question basically becomes: *Was there any C++ standard or non-standard C++ implementation (in GCC, preferably) in which in a variable declared in a `for-init-statement` lived in a different scope than either the loop body or the sorrounding code?*

Comment: Is there some reason you can't fix the code itself?

Comment: Of course I can. I am more interested in *why* this happens (especially when I pass `-fno-for-scope`, which, judging by the description, is quite unrelated).

Comment: Getting this code to compile is *the wrong thing to do*. Fix the redeclaration instead. You absolutely shouldn't be trying to figure out how to defeat the compiler's static analysis.

Comment: IMHO you should fix the code and submit a patch so others don't scratch their head or feel your current frustration.

Comment: I suspect it's because with `-fno-for-scope`, the `int i` is part of the enclosing scope, not the loop body scope.  ie. it becomes similar to `{ int i; { long i; .... } ...stuff after loop... }`.  Without `-fno-for-scope`, it looks more like `{ { int i; long i; ... }  ...stuff after loop...}`, where both get declared in exactly the same scope level.

Comment: @JoeZ Yes, `-fdump-tree-original` confirms this suspicion. However, this behaviour only partially corresponds to what I am looking for: now the declarations clash with `...stuff after loop...`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error redeclaring a for loop variable within the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122542/error-redeclaring-a-for-loop-variable-within-the-loop)