# Error redeclaring a for loop variable within the loop

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

Consider this snippet of a C program:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int i = 10;  // <- Note the local variable

    printf("%d", i); 
}
```

It compiles without any error and, when executed, it gives the following output:

```
1010101010
```

But if I write a similar loop in C++:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     int i = 10;

     std::cout << i; 
}
```

The compilation fails with this error:

```
prog.cc:7:13: error: redeclaration of 'int i'  
     int i = 10;  
         ^  
prog.cc:5:13: note: 'int i' previously declared here  
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
             ^
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is this supposed to be C or C++?

Comment: This is C++. Notice the cout.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous I also notice that `cout` is not working according to OP.

Comment: I suspect OP might be compiling both for C++ and C and asking about the different results.

Comment: FYI, `i` in the `int i=0` and `int i=10;` are different. `int i=10;` scope is within the loop only, not outside. I don't think it gives error.

Comment: Question is not that bad. It is all bout scope of the variable and the way it is behaving differently in c and c++.

Comment: _"While in C++, the scope of the init-statement and the scope of statement are one and the same, in C the scope of statement is nested within the scope of init-statement:..."_ see example just below the quote: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: Could you repose this so it could plausibly compile in c too? That is, remove the cout. There’s a good question buried here.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Have you seen the original my comment is related to?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The edit is my fault. I think I've interpreted the OP's intent, but you can rollback if you think I'm wrong.

Comment: @Bob__ Your edit made the question to get +9 :) Let's leave it as is.

Comment: I honestly don't get the point of this question. It sounds like you're asking "why do C and C++ do this differently", to which the answer is just... C and C++ are different languages. They're very similar in some ways, for sure, but they aren't the same, and expecting one to be a perfect subset of the other is going to lead to disappointment. With that said, I do _like_ this question, and it's interesting to explore the differences -- but it doesn't feel like a good Stack Overflow question. If it was reworded a little to ask about C++, with the C as an example, that might be better.

Comment: It's perfectly clear what the question is asking. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 25):

This is because C and C++ languages have different rules about re-declaring variables in a scope nested in a `for` loop:

- `C++` puts `i` in the scope of loop's body, so the second `int i = 10` is a redeclaration, which is prohibited
- `C` allows redeclaration in a scope within a `for` loop; innermost variable "wins"

Here is a demo of a [running C program](https://ideone.com/q3U5Ou), and a [C++ program failing to compile](https://ideone.com/OLwbeJ).

Opening a nested scope inside the body fixes the compile error ([demo](https://ideone.com/cnGGXs)):

```
for (int i =0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    {
        int i = 10;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Now `i` in the `for` header and `int i = 10` are in different scopes, so the program is allowed to run.

Comment: Got one doubt `for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                int i=10;
                cout<<i;
        }` Is it comes under redeclaration or not. Its `C++`  code and it doesn't produce any error.

Comment: @achal It should produce redeclaration error, because in C++ the `for` loop has a single scope for the body and the variable declared in the header.

Comment: actually only old C allows that and that's because  loop iterator was belonging to global scope. Ofc, you can declare same id in scope below. That was changed in C99.

Comment: @Swift; That's not true at all.

Comment: @Swift: it used to be like this in an old VC++, VC++ 6? don't remember

Comment: @AndriyTylychko down to TurboC++, QuickC (not C++) and before, ofc, now people say 'It's not so" because clang and gcc implement that differently and behaves differently if you use appropriate -std flag. That was result of dubious definition in standard text, which was defining init statement in scope that was higher than loop body, then somewhere in notes added: but you can't use same identifiers. Note, the C89 didn't allowed declaration of variable inside of for() header. But compilers had that already. The mess with for() loop, initializer and virtual keyword are historical issues.

Answer (score 20):

Unlike C, C++ has the rule,
C++11-§6.5.3/1:

> The `for` statement
>
> ```
> for ( for-init-statement conditionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     for-init-statement 
>     while ( condition ) {
>         statement 
>         expression ;
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> except that names declared in the *for-init-statement* are in the **same declarative-region** as those declared in the condition [...]

This means that the scope of the `for-init-statement` and the `statement` are the same<sup>*</sup> and the code below will cause error

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     int i = 10;    // Invalid. 
     // ...
}
```

In C,
C11-§6.8.5/5:

> An iteration statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of its enclosing block. **The loop body is also a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the iteration statement**.

Therefore, `statement` has it's own scope and the above code is valid and equivalent to

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    {
         int i = 10;    // Valid. 
         // ...
    }
}
```

---

<sub>Suggested reading: n3337: 6.5.1 The while statement/p(2). Same reference can be found in c++17 draft (n4659) in section § 9.5.1 and §9.5.3 .</sub>

Comment: N3242 is a pre-C++11 draft; surely suggested reading should be the latest standards and/or latest draft

Comment: @M.M; By latest you mean draft n4741?

Comment: Something like that, yeah. The latest standard is N4659

Comment: @M.M; OK. Updated.

Comment: I don't think the C++ standard language actually justifies marking the example in the question as an error. There are actually two levels that separate the `int i=0` of the _for-init-statement_ from the `int i=10;` contained in the loop body. First off, the replacement text after "is equivalent to" introduces extra braces around the _statement_, which the exception stated in words **does not refer to**, since it only talks about the _for-init-statement_ and the _condition_ (my italics) being on the same declarative level; it does not mention the loop body at all.(...)

Comment: Second, in the example the _statement_ (loop body) is actually a _compound-statement_ (i.e., its outermost tokens are braces), and those braces remain in the replacement text, which therefore becomes concretely `{ int i=0; while(i<5) { {int i=10; cout << i << endl;} i++; } }`, with visibly two more levels of braces around `i=10` than around `i=0`. Even if one construes the badly worded exception to be intended to effectively peel off one level of braces, there is one pair that will remain. Note by the way that putting double braces around the loop body makes reported the error go away.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen; I would say this a poor reading of texts in the answer. I would highly recommend you to read the answer again from top to bottom and then see the section  §6.5.1 and  §6.5.3 to get the full picture.

Comment: I did read those sections before I wrote my comments; what makes you think I did not? By the way I also read in 6.5 "If the substatement in an iteration-statement is a single statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten to be a compound-statement containing the original statement" which means you effectively get a pair of braces even if you wrote a loop body that does not have any (but this is not applicable in the example), and 6.3 "A compound statement defines a block scope" with no exceptions or modifications whatsoever. So every loop body is a _separate_ block scope

Comment: By the way, I think one point is that §6.5.3/1 **should** have said "...except that names declared in the for-init-statement are in the same declarative-region as those declared
in the **statement**", which would at least correspond to the intention of marking the example as an error. It would still not be a very good formulation, since it should only refer to names declared at the outermost level inside _statement_.

Comment: Also it is IMHO a bad idea in the first place to _define_ the meaning of X by saying "construct X is equivalent to Y except that it has some different property", since there is then no way to know how X got to get that property different. Better is to describe the meaning if X directly to get all the details clear; possibly add as a comment that this is almost the same as Y, and point out where the subtle difference lies.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not redeclaration.**

See this carefully...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    int i = 5;
    printf("new i = %d\n", i);
}
```

Output of the above code:-

```
i = 0
new i = 5
i = 1
new i = 5
i = 2
new i = 5
i = 3
new i = 5
i = 4
new i = 5
i = 5
new i = 5
i = 6
new i = 5
```

Clearly, there are two different `i`'s

The newer `i` has a more local scope.

**Is it a bug?**

No

**What is the purpose?**

If it wasn't allowed, it might be very hard to maintain large projects, as you would constantly run into naming collisions.

Generally though, it is considered very poor practice to give the same name to different variables in different scopes, you should avoid doing that whenever possible.

**Why is there no warning message?**

Use `gcc file_name.c -Wshadow` to compile.

---

**EDIT:** ***You can also locally lock the originally declared variables by redeclaring them in for loops.***