# Why does redeclaring the C variable from a loop not affect the loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, scope

Coming from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122542/error-redeclaring-a-for-loop-variable-within-the-loop), why does this loop still run 5 times?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int i = 10;  
    printf("%d\n", i); 
}
```

I'd would guess that as we re-declare `i`, when `i` gets evaluated in the `for`-loop, it would stop the loop after the first cycle. It would be the same as if we just re-assigned `i = 10;`. However, it's as if a new variable is being created, but the loop still uses the previous one. How and why does this happen?

Comment: ```i``` is created within the scope of the loop. in your case it's put on
the stack. At the end of the loop, the stack unwinds and it gets
removed. You then start through the loop again and create a new
variable called again ```i``` on the stack.

Comment: Do study the duplicate: it's all in there. Note that the code you present is not valid C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to scope. Each time you use braces {} you generate a new scope for the program. Anything initialised in that scope will be removed once the scope is exited, which for you is every loop when it exists to check the loop condition.

Using what I have just said we see that you are reinitialising i by saying `int i = 10;` This means you have created a new variable, called i, which has the value 10, within this scope. You can get your desired result by just writing `i = 10;` as it will first look inside the scope for the variable, then it will loop in the next scope above where it will find it in your for loop.

EDIT:

Commenting further on this, it means that you can have the same name for multiple variables as long as they are in different scopes from each other. Like so :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    printf("x = %d\n",x); //check x value equals 10

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        int x = i;
        printf("x = %d\n",x); //a new variable, also called x, now outputs x = i;
    }

    printf("x = %d\n",x); //check x value returns to the original when scope is left
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner variable `i` has a different scope then the one created in `for()`. The for variable gets shadowed, this way and can not be accessed as long as the inner `i` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

This should give us an idea. After the contents of the loop is executed, in the next iteration, the `i` declared inside the loop (between curly braces) is out of scope and only the `i` declared in the `for()` statement is in scope.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    for(int i = 0; printf("i = %d\n", i) && i < 5; i++)
    {
        int i = 10;  
        printf("%d\n", i); 
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
i = 0
10
i = 1
10
i = 2
10
i = 3
10
i = 4
10
i = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the loop's variable belongs to (and is only evaluated in, in your code) in the outer scope.

It can help to think of the classic "for-to-while" transform, which basically states that

```
for(A; B; C)
  D
```

can be transformed to:

```
{
  A
  while(B)
  {
    D
    C
  }
}
```

hopefully this makes it clear that the `for`'s `i` is in the outermost scope and thus not affected by the inner one (which shadows the outer).